# Power BI - how can I exclude certain rows dynamically? I always want rows of one type but want EITHER rows with col1=A or B, never both

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Not sure how best to describe this but here goes.
I have a datatable with rows of resource allocation by staff member, project and date.
I want to always include rows relating to most projects, but there are rows for two specific projects - call them A and B - and I only ever want to include one of these.
I'd like a slicer or some kind of button to specify whether I use A or B, but in my visualisations etc I'd like to display everything except the one not chosen.  [image: Dummy data]

Any ideas?

Comment: provide sample dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your requirement correctly, but this solution should apply.

#### Suggestion 1

Create a custom column:

```
Col1 = SWITCH(table[project], 
   "A", "A project",
   "B", "B project",
   "Other projects")
```

Create a slicer based on `Col1` and then you can use that as a slicer (it will show 3 values).

#### Suggestion 2

One other alternative could be to create a separate table with a many to many relationship to your data table, for example, for this table:

[image: data]

You can create the following table:

[image: types]

Notice how I've repeated project names (other than Assumption and Actuals and have assigned them the two different types). Then you just need a many-to-many relationship between project and project name and use a slicer based on "Type".

#### Suggestion 3

Create a table with just the 2 options (no relationship to the rest of the model):

[image]

Then in your measures, instead of just doing a plain SUM, take the Option as a filter, for example:

```
Days Allocated = 
VAR option = SELECTEDVALUE(Options[Project], "AL (Actual)") //default to Actual

RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Allocation]), KEEPFILTERS(Data[Project] <> option))
```

[demo](https://file.io/I2ehs2cYHkzM)

Comment: HI, I think this needs a step more to give what I need. Hopefully this sample data helps

Comment: The real data has many more variables, notably staff name, but I want something which can sum the number of days allocated by project, by month, by staff member.
For the sum by month or staff member I want to include Brexit, Covid, Core tasks and EITHER AL (Actual) OR AL (Assumption).

Comment: cool, added a couple of suggestions and a demo file

Comment: Thanks so much - I'll look over those and if it solves the problem I'll choose it as a solution - might be a bit much to try this late on a Friday ;-)

Comment: This works! Thanks again

I went with Suggestion 3 - I had to switch the rows in one col of the table because I wanted to SELECT (eg) Actual and therefore EXCLUDE Assumption from the calc, but that was obv straight forward